# "Undefined offset" Soma de Array multidimensional

Tags: php

Meu sistema, lê os arquivos XML dentro de uma pasta e coloca os dados ("número da nota fiscal", "código do produto","quantidade") dentro de um array.

Criei um novo array para ter o total por produto, onde a conta está correta, e o resultado é o que eu espero.

O problema é que eu recebo erro abaixo:

```
 Erro na Linha: #160 :: Undefined offset: 10452
C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php

Erro na Linha: #160 :: Undefined offset: 10485
C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php

Erro na Linha: #160 :: Undefined offset: 10433
C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php

Erro na Linha: #160 :: Undefined offset: 3767
C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php

Erro na Linha: #160 :: Undefined offset: 3768
C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php

C:\xampp\htdocs\controledeentregasver209112019\Romaneio\RomaneirodeCarregamentoTeste_1.php:171:
array (size=5)
  10452 => float 30
  10485 => float 20
  10433 => float 10
  3767 => float 40
  3768 => float 30
```

Segue o código fonte:

```
    <?php  

$notaPesoQuantidade = [];
$totalizando=[];

// ****************PEGANDO OS ARQUIVOS DA PASTA
$path   = "./arquivos/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    if($value=='.' ||$value=='..'):     
    else:
     $arquivo = simplexml_load_file('./arquivos/'."$value");


foreach($arquivo->NFe as $key => $xml){ 
//dados DA nf
$nNF = "".$xml->infNFe->ide->nNF.""  ; 
}
?> 



<?php
//IMPRIMINDO OS PRODUTOS DA NOTA FISCAL
echo "<br/>";

echo "<b><font color=\"#054F77\"> NF-e $nNF ($value) </font></b>";
?>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="color:#4169E1;">COD</th>

      <th scope="col"style="color:#4169E1;">Quant</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php
//PERCORRENDO OS PRODUTOS DA NOTA FISCAL
 foreach ($xml->infNFe->det as $value) {
?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $value->prod->cProd; ?></th>
      <td style="font-weight: bold"><?php echo $value->prod->qCom; ?></td>



  <?php

  $nNF = intval ($nNF);
  $cProd = intval ($value->prod->cProd);
  $qCom= floatval ($value->prod->qCom);



//  $notaPesoQuantidade[$nNF]["$cProd"]=$qCom;

 $notaPesoQuantidade[] = [

         'nota'=>$nNF,
         'produto'=>$cProd,
         'quantidade'=>$qCom



                                 ];



?>       


    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
 </tbody>
</table>



<?php





echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>";  
echo "<br>";  



endif;




}



echo "<b><font color=\"#054F77\"> ***************** CARREGAMENTO TOTAL ******************</font></b>";



foreach ($notaPesoQuantidade as $key => $value) :
    //$key = indice do array
    //$value = é o arrai, ex $value['nota']
    $p = $value['produto'];
    $q = $value['quantidade'];


          $totalizando[$p]+=$q;





endforeach;




  var_dump($totalizando);



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi mudar a lógica. primeiro coloquei tudo em um array por produtos e depois somei.

```
$compras[$cProd][] = $qCom;
```

Soma:

```
foreach ($compras as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/>" . "$key = " . array_sum($value) . "<br/>";
}
```